# Matrix triangularisation through basis swaps exclusively

Tags: matrices

Assume $A$ is a $n \times n$ Matrix with real valued elements.
I would like to bring A into a (lower) triangular form.
However, to do so I am only allowed to swap bases.
Hence, I can only swap rows and columns together.

**Q:** Under which condition is this possible, and does somebody know of any algorithm to do so?

To give a picture, this is a valid operation:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & x \\ 0 & 0 & c
\end{array}
\right) \rightarrow \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & c & 0 \\ 0 & x & b
\end{array}
\right)
$$

However a matrix of the following form can not be brought to a triangular form under this conditions:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & b & x_{2} \\ 0 & x_{1} & c
\end{array}
\right)
 \text{ or } \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 0 \\ x_{1} & c & x_{2} \\ x_{3} & x_{4} & b
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a directed graph with the nodes labeled $1$ through $n$ and an edge from node $i$ to $j$ iff $i\ne j$ and $A_{ij}\ne 0$.

Your operation is possible if and only if this graph is **acyclic**. If the graph *is* acyclic, you get a triangular matrix by arranging the basis vectors in an order corresponding to a [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the graph.

There are well-known algorithms to determine efficiently whether a graph is acyclic, e.g. [Tarjan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) -- or simply try to construct a topological sorting greedily (that is, repeatedly take a node whose predecessors have all been taken already) and see if you get stuck before you get to all nodes.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! Could you help me derive the resulting constraints to the matrix? Sadly, I have very little knowledge about graph theory